# TestNG. Export test results in IDEA IntelliJ

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, reporting, testng

There is an option in IDEA IntelliJ, that you can export test results (after running TestNG tests) in HTML or XML format. I am wondering, is it possible to generate them by default?

[image: this is what I am talking about]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the default [TestNG logging reporters](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters) and what seems to be a cosmetically improved version, [ReportNG](http://reportng.uncommons.org/). Depending on your build system, you can take advantage of what's already being provided, or you can supply your own implementation.